# Current status of SVG parameters implementation

Tags: svg, dynamicparameters

What is the current status of the implementation of parameters in SVG?

We can find some proposals online (dating from 2009), but I have no clue of the current status.

- https://dev.w3.org/SVG/modules/ref/master/SVGRefPrimer.html
- https://tabatkins.github.io/specs/svg-params/ (doesn't seem referenced anymore in the linked repo)

(my goal is to be able to dynamically edit texts in a SVG)

Comment: Dead. Nailed to the perch. The proposal comes with a javascript implementation that still works and you may be able to use css variables instead depending on the specifics of your use case.

Comment: What a pity ...

Comment: I would more call it "wait till the cows come home" ("Saint-Glinglin" in french, I think). There is still an official item in the [SVG 2.1 wishlist.](https://github.com/w3c/svgwg/issues/128).